# Implement Drawer using CupertinoPageScaffold

Tags: flutter

We can easily add drawer using `Scaffold` widget `drawer` property. I want to add a Drawer inside `CupertinoPageScaffold` but there is no property like `drawer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package called [flutter_inner_drawer 0.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inner_drawer) which lets you implement a left or right drawer and can have any type of `Widget` as a `child`.

see an [example here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inner_drawer#-example-tab-).